# How to assign an array's values to a range?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm trying to assign a 1-dimensional array's values to cell range.

For example; my array has 23 items (every item randomized from 1 to 5) and my cell range is range A1 to I7.
I want to assign every value of my array to this cell range randomly.
I randomize the cell values with my array but my array's values are not completely assigned to cells.

```vb
Sub define_ore_body()
    Dim lb_grade As Integer, ub_grade As Integer
    Dim ore_body(1 To 23) As Variant
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
    Dim a As Object
    Dim b As Range
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'my selected range area A1toI7
    Set b = Application.Range("A1:I7")
    Set a = Application.Cells
    
    '******* low and high ore bound ******
    lb_grade = InputBox("Enter lowest ore grade:")
    ub_grade = InputBox("Enter highest ore grade:")
    'The reason why I do it as follows is that if the random lower bound does not start from 1, 
    'the largest random number it generates is 2 more than the value I have entered, so
    If lb_grade > 1 Then
        ub_grade = ub_grade - 2
    End If
    
    '******* Random Array ******
    'array has 23 items
    For i = 1 To 23
        ore_body(i) = Int((ub_grade * Rnd) + lb_grade)
    Next i
    
    '******* filling random cells with my array******
    k = 1
    For Each a In b
        If a.Value = "" And k < 23 Then
            b(Int(7 * Rnd + 1), (8 * Rnd + 1)) = ore_body(k)
        ElseIf a.Count > 23 And k > 23 Then
        Exit For
        Else
        k = k + 1
        End If
    Next a
    
    '******* after filling cell now fill empty cells with Zero******
    For i = 1 To 7
        For j = 1 To 9
            If Cells(i, j) = "" Then
                    Cells(i, j) = 0
            Else
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    
    '******* Coloring only containing array values******
    For i = 1 To 7
        For j = 1 To 9
            If Cells(i, j) > 0 Then
                Application.Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 38
            Else
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. There are 63 cells in A1:A17 so if you only have 23 values then only 23 cells in that range will be filled.

Comment: Hi @norie, yes I want to fill these 23 values into 63 cells randomly and other 40 cells will be filled with zero.

Comment: Then you need another 40 elements in your array, containing zeroes; if you declare the array `(1 To 63) As Long` then all its elements will initialize to `0`. Being a `Variant`, your current array is initializing with `Variant/Empty`, which is *equivalent* to `0` in calculations, and implicitly converts to `0` in many situations - but `Variant/Empty` is what you get out of an entirely blank cell, and that's what will be dumped into cells if you just resize the array.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon yes and in the code, I can fill the rest of the cells with zero but I can't fill with all items of my array. It fills only 18 to 21 (or similar) items of the array every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Loop through the array.
2. Set **a** to a random cell in the range A1:I7.
3. If cell is empty put the value from the array in the cell, if it
   isn't repeat step 2

```vb
Sub define_ore_body()
Dim lb_grade As Integer, ub_grade As Integer
Dim ore_body(1 To 23) As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
Dim a As Range
Dim b As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'my selected range area A1:I7
    Set b = Application.Range("A1:I7")

    ' clear A1:A17
    b.Clear

    '******* low and high ore bound ******
    lb_grade = InputBox("Enter lowest ore grade:")
    ub_grade = InputBox("Enter highest ore grade:")
    'The reason why I do it as follows is that if the random lower bound does not start from 1,
    'the largest random number it generates is 2 more than the value I have entered, so
    If lb_grade > 1 Then
        ub_grade = ub_grade - 2
    End If

    '******* Random Array ******
    'array has 23 items
    For i = 1 To 23
        ore_body(i) = Int((ub_grade * Rnd) + lb_grade)
    Next i

    '******* filling random cells with my array******
    For k = 1 To 23
        Do
            Set a = b.Cells(Int(7 * Rnd) + 1, Int(9 * Rnd) + 1)
        Loop Until a.Value = ""

        a.Value = ore_body(k)
    Next k

    '******* after filling cell now fill empty cells with Zero******
    For i = 1 To 7
        For j = 1 To 9
            If Cells(i, j) = "" Then
                Cells(i, j) = 0
            Else
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    '******* Coloring only containing array values******
    For i = 1 To 7
        For j = 1 To 9
            If Cells(i, j) > 0 Then
                Application.Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 38
            Else
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The array contains 23 items that initialize to `Variant/Empty`:

```
Dim ore_body(1 To 23) As Variant
```

Make that 63 items that initialize to `0`:

```
Dim ore_body(1 To 63) As Long
```

The rest of the code will now populate the first 23 elements, because that's what the loop does:

```
For i = 1 To 23
```

If you want the loop to run through all indexes, consider using `LBound` and `UBound` operators to programmatically retrieve the lower and upper boundaries of the array, respectively:

```
For i = LBound(ore_body) To UBound(ore_body)
```

Note that you have `23` hard-coded in several places, which is going to make it harder than necessary to modify if/when that 23 needs to be come a 25. Consider replacing every occurrence of it by a `Const`:

```
Const ElementCount As Long = 23
```

Then every instance of `23` can become `ElementCount`, and then when it needs to become 25 then there's only one place that needs any code to change.